# Can I make Django perform some function when a model's field changes?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

Here is my Django Model:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime(
            year=2016, 
            month=10, 
            day=3, 
            hour=9, 
            minute=3, 
            second=1,
        ), 
        null=False, 
        blank=False, 
        editable=False,
    )
```

I would like to trigger a certain action when the system's current date/time equals the value of any instance's my_timestamp field. What is the best way to do it? I could run Chron job that continuously ran and polled the all the instances. But that seems messy. Is there a way I can trigger this event without constant wasteful polling?

Can I register some kind of callback that would accomplish this for me?

Comment: What is the resolution at which you want to trigger the check? Every second? Every minute? Every 5 minutes? Any callback you could register would have to be executed at that resolution - callbacks are anyways event based not time based.

Comment: I'm not sure. Suppose it was every minute. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes it can be done; and to answer your next question on optimization - this will depend on the volume of data and what kind of update you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Django signals provide this functionality. They allow you to hook into multiple parts of Django, model CRUD being one of them.

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/

For a list of signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Celery Periodic Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) or create custom manage.py command and use raw cron to start it.